# "go to" vs "go for" vs "go on"

Tags: verbs, prepositional-objects

What's the difference between "*go to*", "*go for*" and "*go on*"?

When can we use each of them?

For example:

[books.google.ru](https://books.google.ru/books?id=uVPABAAAQBAJ&pg=PA61&dq=%22go%20for%20an%20audition%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwis-pa4sankAhXLyKQKHaYLCrAQ6AEITTAE#v=onepage&q=%22go%20for%20an%20audition%22&f=false):

> **1.** At the age of ten my teacher suggested I should **go for an audition** at the Royal Ballet School and I was fortunate enough to be accepted.

[books.google.ru](https://books.google.ru/books?id=7QzJCgAAQBAJ&pg=PT193&lpg=PT193&dq=%22If%20you%20go%20to%20an%20audition,%20and%20you%20look%20horrible,%20who%27s%20going%20to%20hire%20you%22&source=bl&ots=lKOJxXCVSN&sig=ACfU3U08DXbyfZ4UQ00MxIxh4zojNgqC0A&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi0xL_48q3iAhWt-yoKHfERBckQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22If%20you%20go%20to%20an%20audition%2C%20and%20you%20look%20horrible%2C%20who's%20going%20to%20hire%20you%22&f=false):

> **2.** If you **go to an audition**, and you look horrible, who's going to hire you?

[books.google.ru](https://books.google.ru/books?id=r3uYDwAAQBAJ&pg=PT41&dq=%22go%20on%20an%20audition%22&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUi8DE9a3iAhUN4KYKHRDECBsQ6AEIKTAA#v=onepage&q=%22go%20on%20an%20audition%22&f=false):

> **3.** When you **go on an audition**, you're not guaranteed a job, or even a fair shot at a job.

Thanks!

Comment: In the first sentence, "go for" is a phrasal verb that means to make an attempt at.  In the second sentence, the verb is simply "go" and "to" appears as a preposition that introduces the destination where the subject will arrive as a result of performing the intransitive action of the verb.  In the third sentence, "go on" is a phrasal verb that means initiate or undertake, like when one goes on a walk or goes on hiatus.

Comment: You are mixing up two uses. One is phrasal verbs. The other is to-infinitives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like an audition can be perceived in several ways.

> At the age of ten my teacher suggested I should go for an audition at the Royal Ballet School and I was fortunate enough to be accepted.

"go *for*" can introduce a particular purpose, goal, end, or aim (*go for the gold*, *go for some milk* [i.e. do a quick bit of shopping], *go for glory*); go to the audition for the purpose of  showing your talents

> If you go to an audition, and you look horrible, who's going to hire you?

"go *to*" can introduce a scheduled or planned event typically attended by many others as well (a dance, a showing of a film,  a county fair)

> When you go on an audition, you're not guaranteed a job, or even a fair shot at a job.

"go *on*" introduces a defined experience but one that unfolds over an extended time, and thus one where you must be open to an element of chance (compare *go on a safari*, *go on a cruise*, *go on a date*, *go on a pub crawl*)

Comment: P.S. Some writing instructors would encourage a rewrite on the first sentence: "My teacher suggested *to me at the age of ten*..."

Answer (score 0):

Benjamin Harman commented:

> In the first sentence, "go for" is a phrasal verb that means to make an attempt at. In the second sentence, the verb is simply "go" and "to" appears as a preposition that introduces the destination where the subject will arrive as a result of performing the intransitive action of the verb. In the third sentence, "go on" is a phrasal verb that means initiate or undertake, like when one goes on a walk or goes on hiatus.

Answer (score 0):

To add:

*Go for* can also mean *lunge at* as in an attempt to attack someone, grab onto someone, or a dog lunging at another dog or person in an attempt to bite them.

*Go on* can also be a phrase of encouragement as in: *Go on, you can do it!*. It can also be a command meaning *proceed, continue*.